# NPPExec show .err file in console

Tags: notepad++, pic, nppexec

I'm using nppexec to compile files with ccsc compiler for PIC micro controllers.
It's working great, but the ccsc compiler is writing errors/warnings in a separate file.
http://pastebin.com/yNrytafg

Console doesn't show any errors.

What can I do to show the file in the nppexec console so I can click the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Add "+STDOUT +EX" parameters.
With +STDOUT errors are shown in the console, and with +EX the errors are formatted like gcc errors (for simpler filters)

Here are all excecute commands I have used:

```
npp_save
CD $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
cmd /c del project.ESYM
cmd /c del project.o
cmd /c del project.HEX
cmd /c del project.LST
cmd /c del project.ERR
cmd /c del project.COF
cmd /c del project.mcs
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PICC\Ccsc.exe" +FH "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" +Y=9 +EA +STDOUT +EX
```

Console Output Filter:

```
%ABSFILE%:%LINE%:*:  Error*
%ABSFILE%:%LINE%:*:  Warning*
```